# Android - One activity multiple fragments for tabs screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, bottomnavigationview, fragmentmanager

I want to create an app. First page is a login page, then second page is a tabbad screen. I use `BottomNavigationView` to create a tab bar.

I want to give toolbar to each page. So, I put a Toolbar in fragment's layout.

But I have some problems:

1. If I add bottom navigation view to activity, I cannot use any transition animation from login to tab bar page.
2. If I add bottom navigation view to fragment and replace fragment by using childFragmentManager when bottom navigation view item is selected, childFragmentManager doesn't hide parent fragment's toolbar.

For second case, parent `Fragment` toolbar overlays child fragment toolbar.

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.rootFragmentLayout, fragment).commit();
```

Fragment layout is below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/rootFragmentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolBarLayout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood it correctly, one Activity will house multiple fragments with only one toolbar. What you can do is use ViewPager to change between fragments. You'll need a ViewPager on your xml below your toolbar and then you can create a adapter that switches fragments for you.

In this example you supposedly have buttons to switch your fragments, as i call it btn1, btn2 and btn3 on the code

**activity.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include layout="@layout/your_toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Activity.java**

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class mActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        container.setAdapter(adapter);
        container.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
        // This means 3 fragments, change the number as you like
        container.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        container.setCurrentItem(1);  
    }

    // Use this method so your toolbar views switch the fragments
    @OnClick({R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3})
    public void onViewClicked(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn1:
                container.setCurrentItem(0, true);
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                container.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                break;
            case R.id.btn3:
                container.setCurrentItem(2, true);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

**PagerAdapter.java**

```
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                return new YourFragmentClass1();
            case 1:
                return new YourFragmentClass2();
            case 2:
                return new YourFragmentClass3();
            default:
                return new YourFragmentClass1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use viewPager, it is ok for tab switches. But If I can navigate to tab1/xmenu/xmenuDetail, same problem exiss at this point. I will replace `viewPagerFragment1. getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.rootFragmentLayout, fragment).commit();`